# search bar not find all words

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have a problem with the search, it doesn't search for each letter individually, these only if it is word is together, for example: I search Kate it will find but if I type Kae (that still has the letters in it), he won't find it, why?

```
filteredData = contacts.filter {
filteredData = contacts.filter {
  name in return
  name.firstName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || 
  name.lastName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ||
  name.telephone.removeCharacters(
    from:CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
}
```

i attach screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgx4.gif)

I searched around the web and did not find a solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no native Swift method to accomplish what you want but you can implement your own String method to check if the string contains the characters in sequence diacritics and case insensitively as follow:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func containsCharactersInSequence<S: StringProtocol>(
        _ string: S,
        options: String.CompareOptions = []
    ) -> (result: Bool, ranges: [Range<Index>]) {
        var found = 0
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        var index = string.startIndex
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        while index < string.endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...]
                .range(
                    of: string[index...index],
                    options: options
                ) {
            ranges.append(range)
            startIndex = range.upperBound
            string.formIndex(after: &index)
            found += 1
        }
        return (found == string.count, ranges)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let search = "kte"
let tableViewSource = [
    "Anna Haro",
    "Daniel Higgins",
    "David Taylor",
    "Hank Zakroff",
    "John Appleseed",
    "Kate Bell"
]

let filtered = tableViewSource.filter {
    $0.containsCharactersInSequence(
        search,
        options: [
            .caseInsensitive,
            .diacriticInsensitive,
        ]
    ).result
}
print(filtered)   // "["Kate Bell"]\n"
```